# Generating variants over a list in Python

Tags: python

Let me have a arbitrary list of positive integers:

```
[2, 2, 3, 5]
```

I need to write a code, which will generate me a list of all products of those integers, enumerated like that:

```
1111, ..., 1115, 1121, ..., 1125, ... 1135, 1235, 2235.
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean variants?

Comment: Where is the 1 coming from?

Comment: In what way is `1111` a "variant" of `[2, 2, 3, 5]`?

Comment: look at itertools package

Comment: a) State the question clearly, i.e. define "variant". b) Post us your code so far and state what's wrong with it. Or else this deserves to be closed as a *'Give me teh codez'* for lack of effort.

Comment: It looks like you're using `1` as a kind of mask, but beyond that the requirements are very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
itertools.product(range(1,3), range(1,3), range(1,4), range(1,6))
```

Docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

A more general solution:

```
itertools.product(*[range(1, n+1) for n in list_nums])
```

Comment: In python 3 it will produce iterator ?!

Comment: @volcano is that a question or an objection?  Yes, in Python 3 this will produce an `itertools.product` object, which is a generator.  I think it does something similar in Python 2

Comment: The problem is that I have to do it with a arbitrary list.

Comment: You can cast this to a list with `list(...)`

Comment: I mean that I have an arbitrary number of numbers in this list. I could have 5, or 10, or 100, or more.